# Delete data from firebase real time database only if BOTH clients disconnect?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Context: 
Android game. (Two)Users can create or join room with an unique room name.

Goal:

1. if user 1 disconnects while user 2 is in room. user 1 can still join back into room.
2. if user 1 and 2 disconnect, firebase should remove room name from storage.

Issue:

How to do goal 2? Because if user close the app, then the app can't tell firebase to remove data.

Comment: Easiest way is to not do it via firebase.  Do it through your server, and have an occassional ping message.  If the ping isn't sent by either, delete the data from the server.

Comment: I've done basic python client/server socket before. Doesn't deploying a server cost money? Any free recommendations?

Comment: AWS has a free tier.  It's not going to be any good if you have any scale, but neither will Firebase be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing built into Firebase to do this automatically, and it won't be possible to reliably do it with only code in your Android app.

The easiest way to do it would be in Cloud Functions, setting up a structure where you have both connections for the room under a single parent node:

```
room_presence: {
  "room_1": {
    "uid1": true,
    "uid2": true
  },
  "room_2": {
    "uid1": true,
    "uid3": true
  }
}
```

Whenever the last presence node gets delete from a room, that room itself also gets deleted automatically (as Firebase never stores a key without a value), so you can [trigger a Cloud Function on the delete of that node](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#set_the_event_handler) and clean up Storage in there.